# How can i make an script in python that executes every xx minutes for yy days and after the time expires it closes the file

Tags: python, timer

I am trying to create and script that performs an snmp walk

```
import subprocess, shlex,threading, time 
def snmpquery():
  cmd='snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost .enterprises.27611.1.4.5.110.24 >> test2.txt\n'
  arg=shlex.split(cmd)
  subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
  time.sleep(5)
timeout = time.time() + 15   # 15 seconds from now
while timeout < time.time():
 snmpquery()
print('end')
```

but the thing is that after 15 secodns the process keeps running.

Comment: If you are using Unix-based system you can make use of cron to launch processes every X minutes/days/etc.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't exit immediately? Because what you wrote should exit immediately as `timeout` will never be less than `time.time()` given that it's initialized as `time.time() + 15` just a line before the while condition. Your condition should be `time.time() < timeout`.

Comment: Thanks that mis places <  was  damaging the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for a generalized solution:

```
import sys
import time

# Shortcut for multi-platform usage
get_timer = time.clock if sys.platform == "win32" else time.time

def schedule_task(task, tick, ttl):
    timeout = get_timer() + ttl
    while get_timer() < timeout:
        task()
        time.sleep(tick)
```

Then you can use it as: `schedule_task(snmpquery, 5, 15)` (just remove `time.sleep()` from your function) but keep in mind that there is an additional execution bias on the task side (plus the loop) so it won't be extremely accurate over long periods of time.